# The Matrix Representation of a Polynomial composed with a Linear Operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be a polynomial on $C$ and let $T$: $V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator, where $V$ is a complex vector space. Suppose $\beta$ is a basis of $V$. Is is true to say
$$f([T]_\beta) = [f(T)]_\beta$$

How might I prove it so?

Answer (score 0):

If $a \in \mathbb C$ then $[aT]_\beta = a[T]_\beta$, and if $S : V \to V$is another linear operator, then $[T+S]_\beta = [T]_\beta + [S]_\beta$ and $[TS]_\beta = [T]_\beta[S]_\beta$, where $TS := T \circ S$. So the answer is yes.